# predicate adj or noun complement?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, nouns

> She is determined to finish this

Is the word *determined* a predicate adjective or a noun complement?

Answer (score 1):

It's closer to predicate adjective.

The word "determined" is a participial form of a verb.  Like an adjective, it can modify nouns, either directly or through some license.  Here, a license for a subject complement is provided by the verb "is".

A predicate nominative subject complement, on the other hand, isn't a modifier so much as it is an additional reference.